# Accessing post data in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am iterating through a hash and displaying the values as radio buttons.  The hash looks like this:

```
{
 1=>["a", "b"], 
 2=>["c"], 
 3=>["a", "d", "f", "g"], 
 4=>["q"] ..
}
```

After selecting the values, the parameters become:

> {  "commit"=>"vote", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"db863239855c9f73b9ae54c37f6b92c858acb56f",
>   "1"=>"a",  "2"=>"c",  "3"=>"d", 
>   "4"=>"q"}

How can I access these values (POST data) in the update method of the controller in order to update the count field?  I have tried like this.

```
@votings = Voting.find(:all, :conditions => {params[:k]=>params[:val]})
@votings.each do |voting|
  voting.update_attribute('vote_count',
  voting.vote_count+1)
end
```

But gives this error:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   The error occurred while evaluating nil.each..

Can anybody tell where I went wrong?

Comment: Why do you insist on community wiki for objective questions? Let these people earn the reputation they deserve.

Answer (score 4):

The `POST` data is stored in the `params` hash.  So if you wanted the value of the parameter 1, you would use `params[:1]`.

Now lets look at :conditions.  In the [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002263) method, the `:conditions` parameter can take a hash, which is what you are providing.  But your code is saying, take the value of `params[:k]` and set it to the value of params[:val].  But `params[:k]` is nil in this example, there is no key `:k` in your params hash.  So when you are searching, you are getting back a nil value for @votings.  Trying to use each on a nil gets you your error.

Answer (score -2):

The reason you are having serious difficulties is because you are working against the conventions baked into Rails.

Try this for size, although it will require throwing away a lot of code you have already written then wondering about the magic Rails just breathed into your application: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes